# Addition of raw_input numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this simple program that adds a list of numbers received and then spits out the total. I've added a `while` condition to break the program by entering `q`. When I hit `q` the output thats returned in `qq`. I tried converting over to `input` instead of `raw_input` but python doesn't like that much. I saw a few examples online of people using sum but I didn't have any success. An thoughts?

```
print 'Welcome to the reciept program'

while True :   
  bills = raw_input('Enter the value for the seat [\'q\' to quit]: ' )
  if bills == 'q' :
    break

for bill in bills : 
  new_number = bill+bill

print '{}'.format(new_number)
```

Comment: what if the user entered is not a number?

Comment: Try `type(bills)` to see what you are using.

Comment: good point Avinash - i'm going through a book that teaches you the basics in 24 hours so data validation is later in the book :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is all over the place.

```
while True: # loop
  bills = raw_input('Enter the value for the seat [\'q\' to quit]: ' ) # get input
  if bills == 'q': # if the input is 'q'
    break # stop asking for input

for bill in bills: # for each character in 'q'
  new_number = bill+bill # double 'q' and save it

print '{}'.format(new_number) # print the number with no special formatting of any kind
```

Try this instead:

```
bills = [] # initialize a list
while True: # loop
    bill = raw_input('Enter the value for the seat [\'q\' to quit]: ' ) # get input
    try: # try to...
      bills.append(float(bill)) # convert this input to a number and add it to the list
    except ValueError: # if it can't be converted because it's "q" or empty,
        break # stop asking for input

result = 0 # initialize a zero
for bill in bills: # go through each item in bills
  result += bill # add it to the result

print result
```

Or, better yet:

```
bills = raw_input("Enter the value for each seat, separated by a space: ").split()
print sum(map(float, bills))
```

This gets a string like `"4 4.5 6 3 2"`, splits it into a `list` on whitespace, turns each of the contained strings into a float, adds them together, and prints the result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I like the comment explanations you provided next to each line, i'm going to do this so it makes it easier to read. I'm getting an error `'str' object has no attribute 'append'` but I'm trying to work through it. Thanks for the starting point

Comment: @RomeNYRR - My mistake; I had initialized the `list` as `bill` rather than the proper `bills`, and it looks like you had been previously using that interpreter for the older code where `bills` was a string.

Comment: Thank you!! The comments helped clear it up and I was able to follow it all the way through.

Answer (score 3):

The value of bills is "q".  Your `for` loop is iterating over the (1) characters in that string.  Inside the loop, the value of `bill` is "q", so `new_number` is "qq".